# Generate layers positions in Photosop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, page-layout, layout

How I can generate grid/layout guides with positions of all layers in photoshop and save it? 
I would like to look like this, but for all elements in document. If it is not possible to generate, how I can quickly draw pixel perfect lines with it lengths?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found free solution [here](http://ink.chrometaphore.com/).  Essentially it is spec plugin. There is several option on the market, most of them are paid. Ink will do the job in most cases.